# How can I prevent my banana tree from drying out?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, dryness, banana

We live in Lahore , Pakistan where temperature in summers reach 45 degrees Centigrade. Our banana tree is drying out in the sun. What is the best way to ensure that it remains healthy? This banana tree is only for decorative purposes. It does not bear fruit.

Here is a picture of our banana tree:

[image]

And our neighbours banana tree pic:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like a humidity issue. This could be difficult to treat in a large outdoor specemin. Is there a way you could provide some shade/sun protection to help prevent water loss?

Comment: Please send a picture of your plant that includes its environment, the ground.  Send another picture of your neighbor's plant as well...go to your plant nursery and get a big chunk of 'shade cloth'.  The wind blows through it and won't damage your plant.  Ummm...how big is this plant?

Comment: I'm thinking water and possibly nutrition. What are the symptoms that you are seeing? As well as mist, try drip watering. We're growing bananas here in Texas - not quite as hot as you, but humidity much less than their native cloud/rainforests (fruit are rare due to winter frosts).

Comment: I've added pictures of our banana tree and that of our neighbours. Our rainy season should commence around this time of the year which means more rain water and less sun due to cloud covering. Do you think that would help it or should I still employ a shade?

Comment: @haanimasood - nice looking area - I can see the banana is very exposed, not even remotely jungle like there, is it!

Comment: Must be painful to see neighbors banana tree doing so well.
- India

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bananas like to grow in temperatures between 26-30 deg C, in high humidity, which means your 45 degrees is a bit much for it, particularly if it's in an unshaded position. They grow best in 'jungle' conditions, meaning with other plants giving some relief and shade from hot midday and afternoon sun. They also don't like being exposed to a lot of wind, so in other words, your plant will do best if its surrounded and slightly shaded by other plants in such a hot climate as yours. If it is in the ground, then a thick mulch (on ground which is already damp) will help, but you do need to provide some shading for it during the hottest part of the day. Obviously, extra watering, possibly misting it with water as often as possible, will help, but that shading is the most essential thing.

Comment: I guess we'll have to employ some shading however our neighbors have a similar tree in similar conditions (which is without a shade)but stays healthy.

Comment: @haanimasood - how long has your tree been planted?

Comment: almost a year now.

Comment: Would our upcoming rainy season (more cloud covering and more rain) help it ? Should still install a shade considering that in the upcoming season there will be less sun and high humidity?

Comment: @haanimasood: shade till it starts, the rains I mean. Bananas don't like being permanently wet at the roots for weeks either though, but if you've not had trouble before in the rains, it should be fine.

Comment: If you look at the stalks, I think your garden could use more compost, decomposed organic matter.  Just spread it on top of your soil, the organisms will incorporate it into your soil profile.  What do you do for fertilizing? A big chunk of shade cloth would be ideal for very hot days.  Don't water at night, just during the day.  This will give lots of humidity.  This banana tree could use some nutrients; fertilizer and decomposed organic matter.